# Stripe Webhook Error: "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload" | NextJS | Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, vercel

This is an error that is extremely popular, however, none of the solutions I have found have worked for me.

I have a NextJs App hosted by Vercel. The Stripe Webhook works locally, however, when it's running remotely on Vercel, I get the following stripe error when it's trying to validate the request: `No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?`

Here's my webhook endpoint in my NextJs app:

```
const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2023-08-16",
});

export async function POST (req) {
  const buf = await req.text();
  const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature');
  let event;
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, webhookSecret); // this triggers the error
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error: Stripe webhook failed: ${err.message}`);
    return NextResponse.json({ received: false, error: err.message}, { status: 400 });
  }
  ...
}
```

This line is causing the error: `event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, webhookSecret);` I know the `sig` and `webhookSecret` is correct, I've checked it too many times. The odd thing here is that the same webhook request works locally but not remotely when the App is hosted on Vercel. Many people talk about app middleware being the issue but in this case, would it be Vercel middleware? I haven't been able to find any instances of people having issues with Vercel interfering with the Stripe webhook.

I've tried retrieving the raw req body in various ways, none of which worked:

```
import {buffer} from "micro";
const buf = await buffer(req);
stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf.toString(), sig, webhookSecret);
```

```
import getRawBody from 'raw-body';
const rawBody = await getRawBody(req);
stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, webhookSecret);
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: @KenWhite that worked, thank you! I was using the value on the top right of the webhook endpoint page thinking it was the webhook secret. But in fact you need to use the "Signing secret"!

Answer (score 2):

I made a very simple mistake. I was using the value on the top right of the stripe webhook endpoint dashboard (that starts with "we_") thinking it was the webhook secret. But in fact you need to use the "Signing secret" that is also located on the stripe webhook endpoint dashboard and is located under the endpoint title. It starts with "whsec_". In my example from above, this value should be set to `webhookSecret`

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I did the same mistake and I couldn't find out whats wrong.